# PHP salt and hash SHA256 for login password

Tags: php, mysql, hash, salt, sha256

I've made encrypting of the password in my register script and they are stored in the database, and I have to use them to login, so I would want to use the unencrypted ones to login. I've read some of the threads in here but nothing is helping me. How can I add it in my login.php? The salt is also stored in the database.

This is my register.php script for encrypting

```
$hash = hash('sha256', $password1);

function createSalt()
{
    $text = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
    return substr($text, 0, 3);
}

$salt = createSalt();
$password = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash);
```

and this is my login.php with season

```
//Create query
$qry="SELECT * FROM member WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        //Login Successful
        session_regenerate_id();
        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['username'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['password'];
        session_write_close();
        header("location: profile.php");
        exit();
    }
    else {
        //Login failed
        //error message 
    }
else {
    die("Query failed");
}
```

Comment: You're *hashing*, not encrypting. *Big* difference.

Comment: Don't use plain text passwords for anything. You should **ALWAYS** be hashing or encrypting your passwords.

Comment: There shouldn't be any decrypting of passwords. Best practice is to take the users password and use it to generate your hash and match that result to the database in order to verify credentials.

Comment: do you want plain text for login in login page or in coding?

Comment: You are not showing how username/password are input from user, nor how you make comparison between input password hash and stored password hash. In fact, I can't figure out how you would do so with you current query, as it seems to me that you need to store your salt to DB for use in comparing input to hashed password.  There is no way to know what the password hash is before retrieving the data from DB. Also, I don't understand why you are hashing the password value twice.

Comment: In your code you use a random salt. How do you want to compare the passwords later if you don't know the salt anymore? Or did you store the salt as well? -- Also please don't use `mysql` functions, use `mysqli` or `pdo`.

Comment: @Mike Brant the salt is stored in the database

Comment: @Simon_says Then why does your query have a password component in it?  Your select query should simply look up by username, then with returned data from DB (including salt and hashed password) make the comparison against input.  There is no possible way you can make a DB query on password hash if you don't yet know the salt needed to create the hash.

Comment: If you are interested, you should have a look into the brand new php >= 5.5 methods called `password_hash` and `password_verify` instead of using your own algorithm (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Comment: I agree with @andreas

Comment: You don't get the unencrypted password back ever. To check login, recreate the salted hash and compare it to $password field to find a match.

Comment: Do you have experience with cryptography? If not then you should probably use existing solutions. The [`password`](http://php.net/password) extensions makes hashing passwords extremely easy. It also ensures that it is done right.

Comment: when I try to use this code in my login.php  
`$member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$hash = hash('sha256', $member['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password) );` 
then it allows me to login without the password, and also if i put the query like this `$query = "SELECT id, username, password, salt
FROM member
WHERE username = '$username';";` it still allows to login without the correct password

Comment: Also see Openwall's [Portable PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (PHPass). Its hardened against a number of common attacks on user passwords.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

These examples are from php.net. Thanks to you, I also just learned about the new php hashing functions.

Read the php documentation to find out about the possibilities and best practices:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

**Save a password hash:**

```
$options = [
    'cost' => 11,
];
// Get the password from post
$passwordFromPost = $_POST['password'];

$hash = password_hash($passwordFromPost, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

// Now insert it (with login or whatever) into your database, use mysqli or pdo!
```

**Get the password hash:**

```
// Get the password from the database and compare it to a variable (for example post)
$passwordFromPost = $_POST['password'];
$hashedPasswordFromDB = ...;

if (password_verify($passwordFromPost, $hashedPasswordFromDB)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

Comment: WHAT IS THIS SORCERY?  Don't you need to apply the salt to the returned user's password before comparing it?

Comment: Wow. No @DigitalChris, you do not. From the php ref: `Note that password_hash() returns the algorithm, cost and salt as part of the returned hash. Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is included in it. This allows the verify function to verify the hash without needing separate storage for the salt or algorithm information. `  Pretty cool.

Comment: We need to use the PASSWORD_BCRYPT constant, as shown in answer, instead of PASSWORD_DEFAULT to ensure that this won't stop working in the future with existing hashes right? `...this constant [PASSWORD_DEFAULT] is designed to change over time` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: No @Programster, PASSWORD_DEFAULT will keep working with no problems. What will stop working is your database query if you limit the column that saves the encrypted password to a length that can't contain it.

Answer (score 3):

According to php.net the Salt option has been deprecated as of PHP 7.0.0, so you should use the salt that is generated by default and is far more simpler

**Example for store the password:**

`$hashPassword = password_hash("password", PASSWORD_BCRYPT);`

**Example to verify the password:**

`$passwordCorrect = password_verify("password", $hashPassword);`

Answer (score 1):

```
array hash_algos(void)

echo hash('sha384', 'Message to be hashed'.'salt');
```

Here is a link to reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't login because you did't get proper solt text at login time.
There are two options, first is define static salt, second is if you want create dynamic salt than you have to store the salt somewhere (means in database) with associate with user.
Than you concatenate  user solt+password_hash string now with this you fire query with username in your database table.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Flo254 chained `$salt` to `$password1`and stored them to `$hashed` variable. `$hashed` variable goes inside `INSERT` query with `$salt`.

Answer (score -2):

You can't do that because you can not know the salt at a precise time. Below, a code who works in theory (not tested for the syntaxe)

```
<?php
$password1 = $_POST['password'];
$salt      = 'hello_1m_@_SaLT';
$hashed    = hash('sha256', $password1 . $salt);
?>
```

When you insert :

```
$qry="INSERT INTO member VALUES('$username', '$hashed')";
```

And for retrieving user :

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM member WHERE username='$username' AND password='$hashed'";
```

Comment: You never store `$salt`. Your theory is off.

Comment: User's original question uses a random salt, which is better than this.

Comment: A salt does not have to be random, it has to be unique. Big difference. Doesn't make this post any more useful.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen You _always_ store salt - just not hard-coded in to the code.  The point being that's it is random and different per-user.  But, it is always stored as that's the only way to verify a password.

Comment: @Jon You misunderstood my comment. The code in this answer never stores the `$salt` variable. Look at the `INSERT` query...

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I understood it.  I was clarifying your first sentence as it can be taken incorrectly without knowing you are referring to the variable used for the salt rather than storing of the salt itself, which is required ^^

Comment: @Jon You actually did misunderstand Sverri's comment, otherwise your reply to his comment makes no sense. "You always store salt - just not hard-coded in to the code" - it was never his point to begin with.

Comment: @ner0 did you notice the last comment you are replying to was posted nearly 7 years ago? 

Comment: @Flo354 Yes, I did, but I thought it was of the utmost importance to the discussion. :D