# Creating new user in MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a `_payments` database with a `users` table with `id`, `username`, `password`. The passwords use hash+salt. My developer is unavailable and i need to create a new user. What query would i run to do this?

Comment: Don't you have an user interface designed to do this, so you don't rely on your developer every time ? You really should.

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764031/php-salt-and-hash-sha256-for-login-password

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way, in a crisis: make a complete copy of one row to another, and edit the user name.

Something like

```
insert into users (username,password) select username,password from users where user_id = [otherID]
```

Then

```
update users set username='newname' where id=[newid]
```

The new user will have the same password as the existing user. If you have a way to change the password using a UI, use that.

Comment: So to create a new password entirely i'd have to understand PHP + MySQL?

Comment: @T2T if you don't understand what you're doing, don't play with the database. Otherwise your next question could be "I accidentally deleted everything, what do I do next ?".

Comment: To create a new password, you need to understand how the passwords are hashed and salted. You can do it with just sql, but without access to the php you may have to guess the hashing/salting mehcanism. Given the questions you're asking, I would recommend great caution.

Comment: What does the hashed password look like?
This might shed some light onto how it's hashed. Beyond that, you really need to do this via PHP scripts. If your developer hasn't provided a way to add and edit users, get a new developer.